# What does a "rep change" event on the reputation tab mean?

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-history

There is an event named *rep change* on [this reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1051924/aki?tab=reputation). The tooltip says "arbitrary rep change":

[image: arbitrary rep change]

What does that mean? When does a "rep change" occur?

Comment: Well, [badge bonuses](http://stackapps.com/users/1377/matt-blaine?tab=reputation) such as [API Evangelist](http://stackapps.com/badges/60/api-evangelist), for one thing. That's clearly not the case here, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the case above there was a very old bug that allowed people to offer a bounty worth more than their current rep.  To fix our mistake we have credited back any rep that would have pushed the running reputation below 1.

Comment: And in [other cases](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/users/8217/naiveai?tab=reputation&sort=time) ?